# New Laptop Win XP Audio driver and alternatives

Tags: windows-xp, audio, drivers

I'm looking for an alternative on how to make audio work on a laptop with XP that probably has no audio driver available:

I installed Win XP on a new Packard Bell Easy Note TE11BZ laptop for a classroom. I managed to get almost every driver I needed, but the audio one is not working.

**How to find that driver:**

I've tried different software options like DriverEasy, but the fact that the driver that it recommends is one for Win7 and doesn't work, seems to be a bad signal.

Booting Ubuntu live works fine and there I can get this information about the driver, in case it is useful:

```
AMD FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d]
```

Any advice on how to find this driver? Or maybe it is not available?

**I'm probably giving up and looking for an alternative:**

I could install another OS (like the mentioned working Ubuntu) and a Virtual Machine to put XP inside. The problem is that many non-techy teachers will use it and it will scare them.

Maybe I could use a usb connector with two female mini-jack plugs that I've got, but I don't even know if it is an audio hardware itself or if it just uses the ordinary audio card.

Is there any other alternative using still XP?

I don't want to upgrade to Win7, nor use its XP mode.

Comment: 'I don't want to upgrade to Win7, nor use its XP mode.' Why not?

Comment: @daxlerod Well... just a personal decision. I want to get out of Windows as a computer administrator. One day I will switch all that building to Linux, but until then I don't want to trespass the XP barrier ; )

Comment: @daxlerod Ah! And XP mode is a kind of a virtual machine, isn't it?

Comment: XP mode on Win 7 is a virtual machine, yes. Mainstream support for XP ended 4.5 years ago. Extended support ends in April 2014. My point is, you need to make a change, maybe this is a good opportunity to start.

Comment: If this machine came with Windows 7 and has hardware that only has drivers for Windows 7 then your only options are to install Windows 7 or find a USB sound card with XP drivers.